# spring boot h2 data init

Tags: spring, spring-boot, initialization, h2

I am trying to load init data to h2

I have User model

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;    
    private String login;
    private String password;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String login, String password) {
        //this.id = id;
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }
    //...getters and setters
}
```

my repository

```
@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

I dont have implementation of UsersRepository. Looks like spriing-boot do it for me, cause I can save and retreive data

Now I am trying to init data by putting data-h2.sql into resource

data-h2.sql

```
INSERT INTO users (login, password) VALUES
  ('user1', 'pass1'),
  ('user2', 'pass2');
```

looks like data export somewhere

HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}

HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found

HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist

HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}

HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export

HHH000230: Schema export complete

But when I am trying retreive data , there is no data

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ApiController {

    final UsersRepository usersRepository;

    public ApiController(UsersRepository usersRepository) {
        this.usersRepository = usersRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public Iterable<User> getUsers() {
        return usersRepository.findAll();
    }
    }
```

What I am missing? Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Can you add **application.properties** file in your questions

Comment: @mrtasln application.properties file is empty

Comment: Can i see your database configurations

Comment: @mrtasln I dont have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add your connection properties in  your **application.properties** file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/Desktop/Database/test;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Then

add your model object `@Table(name = "users")` anotation like below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
....

}
```

Finally change sql script file name **data-h2.sql** to **data.sql**

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it correctly in [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html) you need to add the

`spring.datasource.platform=h2`

property to your ***application properties***. Then spring is searching for the file named data-h2.sql in classpath and executes it.